# How to convert a date and time in one time zone to other in java

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to convert GMT+2 time to GMT-4 time.But i am getting unexpected results.Help me on how to achieve that conversion of one time zone time to other time zone time.

```
originTime = "2015-08-15T10:25:00";
    SimpleDateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");      
        converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
        GregorianCalendar oc = originTime.toGregorianCalendar();
        String OriginStart=converter.format(oc.getTime());
```

The above code has to give the originStart time lesser than the given time If it is GMT-4.
    But Im getting OriginStart time greater than the given time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the timzone strings are valid (as i haven't tried it) try something like

```
String originTime = "2015-08-15 10:25";
SimpleDateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"); 
converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10"));
Date date = converter.parse (originTime);       
converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
String OriginStart=converter.format(date);
```

Comment: "2015-08-15T10:25:00" matches "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

## Padding Zero

Generally, use a padding zero for offset hours. But this is *not* a problem in your specific code. At least not according to the doc for [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class which explicitly accepts single digit.

The ISO 8601 standard requires offset hours to have a padding zero. So use `-04` rather than `-4`.

By the way, the original release of java.time had a bug where it failed to parse offsets values of just hour without menu. So in that case, use `-04:00` rather than `-04`.

## Named Time Zone

A time zone is more that just an offset from UTC (GMT). A time zone includes rules about Daylight Savings Time (DST) and other anomalies, past, present, and future. So use a [specific time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you have one in mind.

An example of a `+02:00` time zone name would be `Africa/Bujumbura`. An example of `-04:00`, `America/Martinique`.

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

The java.util.Date/.Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome and confusing. Perhaps the worst of the bundled Java libraries. Avoid them.

Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

## ISO 8601

The ISO 8601 standard defines sensible unambiguous string formats for date-time values. Your input string format complies with this wise standard.

Both Joda-Time and java.time parse and generate strings in ISO 8601 format by default. So no need to specify a formatter.

## Example

Example code written in Joda-Time 2.7.

Define the input, formatted in ISO 8601 without any offset from UTC.

```
String input = "2015-08-15T10:25:00";
```

Specify time zones if input and output.

```
DateTimeZone zoneInput = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours( 2 );
// DateTimeZone zoneInput = DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Bujumbura" );  // Preferably the specific time zone name.

DateTimeZone zoneTarget = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours( -4 );
// DateTimeZone zoneTarget = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Martinique" );  // Preferably the specific time zone name.
```

Parse the string, while assigning a time zone. Then adjust the time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeOriginal = new DateTime( input , zoneInput );
DateTime dateTimeTarget = dateTimeOriginal.withZone( zoneTarget );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zoneInput / zoneTarget : " + zoneInput + " / " + zoneTarget );
System.out.println( "dateTimeOriginal : " + dateTimeOriginal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeTarget : " + dateTimeTarget );
```

When run.

```
zoneInput / zoneTarget : +02:00 / -04:00
dateTimeOriginal : 2015-08-15T10:25:00.000+02:00
dateTimeTarget : 2015-08-15T04:25:00.000-04:00
```